# Logic Apps and Outlook embedded images

Tags: outlook, azure-logic-apps, imagejpeg

I want to copy embedded images from an outlook email to my blob storage.  I have a step to run a For Each over the email attachments (the embedded images are recognized as attachments).  But the when I look at the raw input for the email message, the attachment[0].contentBytes is Null.  And the error I get when trying to create the blob using setting the blob content to "Attachments Content" is:

"InvalidTemplate. Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Create_blob' inputs at line '1' and column '3316': 'The template language function 'base64ToBinary' expects its parameter to be a string. The provided value is of type 'Null'. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#base64ToBinary for usage details.'."

Here is the Raw Input to the "When new email arrives" step:

```
"Attachments": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.OutlookServices.FileAttachment",
      "Id": "12345",
      "LastModifiedDateTime": "2020-11-22T07:38:19+00:00",
      "Name": "footer.jpg",
      "ContentType": "image/jpeg",
      "Size": 13969,
      "IsInline": false,
      "ContentBytes": null
    }
]
```

Any help with these steps is much appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please click `Add new parameter` and choose `Include Attachments`. select `Yes` for `Include Attachments`:

[image]